# Function called during back button click on Android

Tags: android

Which is the function called when you click the back button on android. My requirement is when an application is running and user clicks on the back button, the status of the application should be stored into the database and the user should be able to see the status whenever he returns back to the application.

Browsing through internet, I understood we can handle the control using `onKeyDown()` function. However even if I use it in my code, the function is not called when I click on back button. Below is the function:

```
  @Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
      Log.d(null,"In on Key Down");
      if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
          moveTaskToBack(true);
          return true;
      }
      return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }
```

Please suggest, if anybody has faced the same/similar scenario.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the Activity lifecycle methods to save and restore state. You could save your state during onPause and restore in onResume. In your activity:

```
 @Override
protected void onPause()
{
super.onPause();
    //Save state here
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
super.onResume();
    //Restore state here
}
```

You could also do this in onStart/onStop. Check out the activity lifecycle here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply. I tried overriding onPause() before posting it here, but somehow whenever I press the back button the function is not being called. So am finding an alternative to it.

Answer (score 18):

the activity function called when you press the back button is onBackPressed.

void    onBackPressed()
Called when the activity has detected the user's press of the back key.

upvote if you came here for this and not specifically for saving state :P

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to override the back button behavior to save the status of your activity.

Just override `onPause()` and save any persistent state you want.

Answer (score 0):

Save changes to `SharedPreferences` and commit changes back to your `SQLite` databases in `onPause`. Load them in `onResume`.

For saving the current state of your activity (e.g. which tab the user has open) make use of  `onSaveInstance(Bundle outState)` and the `Bundle` passed to you in `onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)` to store and retrieve this information.

Answer (score 0):

Change the return to false inside the back condition

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        Log.d(null,"In on Key Down");
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            moveTaskToBack(true);
            return false;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you really wanna detect the back button when the user presses it, you have to override onBackPressed() in your activity.
If you wanna store a status in the database you can override the onDestroy method and do storing there. and You can read it in the onCreate() method when the activity is launched again.